# Is there a way to tell last publish date of an azure function?

Tags: azure-functions

Is there a way to tell last publish date of an azure function?
Or is there a way to tag a publish with a version?

I want to know if the function has the latest changes (It may be obvious) but I wander if is any way to check this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you publish any function app on Azure you can check the "Activity log" for any particular operations. (`Platform features -> All settings -> Activity log`). You can find these particular Operations are being logged when you publish.

Activity Log Function:
[image: Activity Log Function]

Comment: but only for last 3 months